# How to use multiple window in chrome browser selenium webdriver and switch the tab if required

Tags: java, selenium

I want to copy a temp email and paste in other sites(twitter)to create a account.
I have completed a copy and paste process but we need to verify the email OTP so for that I have to stay on 1st site

```
driver.get("https://tempail.com/en/");
```

and I need to get the email OTP (How to get the email OTP only the OTP number alone ?)

Below is my entire code :

```
driver.get("https://tempail.com/en/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          
WebElement copyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='eposta_adres']"));
          
String email = copyButton.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(email);
         
        
driver.get("https://mobile.twitter.com/");
    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Sign up with phone or email')]")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
     
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name"))).sendKeys("abc5643754");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Use email instead']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("email"))).sendKeys(email);
Select month = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_1"))));      
Select day = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_2"))));        
Select year = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_3"))));                       
month.selectByValue("10");      
day.selectByValue("14");        
year.selectByValue("1992");
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click();
  }
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Sign up')]"))).click();
```

Now I need to copy the OTP from the temp email site but the site is already closed if I reopen I get new temp email, so we need stay on the 1st URL(tempemail site until we get and capture the OTP from the temp site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem explanation :

You are doing

```
driver.get("https://tempail.com/en/");
```

and then in the same code, later on you are doing

```
driver.get("https://mobile.twitter.com/");
```

Now, let's understand what happens when you do this. It will load the first URL and and after interaction (the code that you've for tempail), and it will load the `https://mobile.twitter.com/` in the same tab.

### Problem Solution :

You should open a new tab using Selenium and load the second URL into that tab. Also make sure to switch between tab as and when needed.

**Sample code :**

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("https://tempail.com/en/");  
WebElement copyButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='eposta_adres']"));
                  
String email = copyButton.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println(email);
                 
String newURL = "https://mobile.twitter.com/";
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.open('"+newURL+"','_blank');");  
ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Sign up with phone or email')]")).click();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("name"))).sendKeys("abc5643754");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[text()='Use email instead']"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("email"))).sendKeys(email);
Select month = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_1"))));      
Select day = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_2"))));        
Select year = new Select(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("SELECTOR_3"))));                       
month.selectByValue("10");      
day.selectByValue("14");        
year.selectByValue("1992");
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Next')]"))).click();
    }
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@dir='auto']//*[contains(text(),'Sign up')]"))).click();

driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(0));
        
Thread.sleep(2000);
String[] otpString  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("a[href] div.baslik"))).getText().split("\\ ");
String otp = otpString[0];
System.out.println("OTP is " + otp);
        
Thread.sleep(2000);
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("verfication_code"))).sendKeys(otp);
```