# How to switch to a new window and print the title in selenium webdriver (without windowhandles)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Iam new to selenium and trying to switch to new amazon tab which I opened and print the title
But when Sending control and Tab nothing happens how to achieve it can anyone help here :)

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
     WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
     driver.get("https://www.amazon.com");
     //Thread.sleep(6000);
     Actions a = new Actions(driver);
      
    List<WebElement> el= driver.findElements(By.xpath("(//div[@class='navFooterColHead'])[1]/../ul/li/a"));
       
     for(int i=0;i<el.size();++i)
     {
      el.get(i).sendKeys(Keys.Control,Keys.Enter);
     }
    
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL +"\t");
```

Comment: How did you open `new amazon tab` ? also what do you mean `(without windowhandles)` ?

Comment: – 
cruisepandey
 sorry my bad I edited code By windowhandles I mean I dont want to use driver.getwindowhandles and switch to the new tab rather I want to use key board shortcut

Comment: Not possible in Selenium, if it's a new tab then you will have to switch to new tab. Selenium do not know how to handle such cases. If this was in Python, there's helium that do not require switching. But it's limited to python.

Comment: Here is one old video here this control tab is working > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVZPa_LX6UU

Comment: your line >  if it's a new tab then you will have to switch to new tab ?? so how you are going to switch

Comment: See in that video he is just printing the title, that's not the real time programming, switching never work only for title there's lot to do. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69091245/how-to-use-multiple-window-in-chrome-browser-selenium-webdriver-and-switch-the-t/69091922#69091922 I have solved a typical and complex problem where I had to go back and forth to get the job done !

Comment: so how you would do here for amazon any way without window handles approach because sometimes you get single id for two tabs so how we will switch to other one>?

Comment: That's why getwindowshandle return set not list. It will always be unique. Check the link I have provided, that's how we do in real time, not like that video, those aren't worthy videos. YouTube should have some policy to verify content, it sucks there anybody can upload anything lol

Comment: Hi thanx There is one website I cannot share it here there when using getwindow handles only 1 id is returned as both having same window id so how to switch to the child tab there ?? that issue so I was chekcking if I can send control tab and switch to new tab

Comment: No two windows can have same ID. Please check again.

Comment: I already used windowhandles and its working but I wanted to see different way ? just like we do manually send control tab from keyboard

Comment: You can do that also, and using index you can switch. But I don't rely on index.

Comment: if 2 tab have same id > xyz how it will identify which id of which one ?

Comment: so before switching you should get the windows handle not handles (plural) and save it to some variable. and use it whenever you'd wish to

Comment: the driver needs the window handle.  Period.  Ctrl-Tab will only switch the tab to the front.  The driver will still be working in the other tab/handle.